# R executable file stops after writing one csv

Tags: r, windows

I made an Rexec file using this tutorial:
http://www.r-datacollection.com/blog/Making-R-files-executable/

I've made one using a files that runs all the way through when I open Rstudio and run it. But, the Rexec file I have made runs up to the first csv, and then stops. Is there a way to keep the Rexec file as one file and have all the csvs run, or must it become multiple files?

The code in question, which exists in one file, is this:

```
    #Measure the time taken
start.time <- Sys.time()

# Load functions in other R files
source("R/Functions.R")
source("R/Negatives Check.R")
source("R/Control Totals.R")
source("R/Validations.R")

# Load Packages
load_packages()

files = load_TZP()
files2 = load_TZP_stacked()

# Negatives Check---------------------------------------------------------------
write_csv(cbind(Name = names(files), create_output()), 
          paste0("Final CSV/Negatives Check ", gsub(":", ".", Sys.time()), ".csv"))
```

## This is where the .Rexec file stops

```
# Control Totals Check----------------------------------------------------------

# Choose limit to account for rounding
total_limit = 10

write_csv(cbind(#Name = control_total_files,
                #Check = control_total_checks,
                create_output_totals()), 
          paste0("Final CSV/Control Totals ", gsub(":", ".", Sys.time()), ".csv"))

# Validations Check-------------------------------------------------------------

# Choose a limit for the difference, to account for rounding errors
limit = 0.1

write_csv(cbind(Name = valid_names,
                Check = valid_checks,
                create_output_geo()), 
          paste0("Final CSV/Validations ", gsub(":", ".", Sys.time()), ".csv"))

# Measure the time taken
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about your working directories (first for RStudio and second for Rexec)? Are they the same?

Maybe, you need to change the working directory in Rexec.

```
# Returns an absolute filepath of current working directory of the R process
getwd()

# setwd is used to set the working directory to dir
setwd("C:/Users/User/Documents") # for example
```

Comment: Thanks, Arkadiy, this solved the issue. The original file was in an R project, which has flexible working directories depending on where you put it. I voted for your comment, but it's not shown because I don't have the reputation.

Comment: You can accept my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers