# Trying to create an executable to auto-run an R-script

Tags: r, automation, windows-7, task, scheduled-tasks

I Googled this a bit, and found a few dead-ends, but I can't seem to create an executable file that runs an R-script.  I am working on Windows 7.  I am looking for a solution that I can double-click, or run on Windows Task Scheduler.  Even if I have to run it using a batch script, that's totally fine.  I am just looking for a way to run an R-script based on a date/time condition.

For instance, if I run this in R, saves some data, in Excel format, on my desktop.

```
target = "http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/meisubs.NSF/log?openagent&5206001_key_aggregates.xls&5206.0&Time%20Series%20Spreadsheet&24FF946FB10A10CDCA258192001DAC4B&0&Jun%202017&06.09.2017&Latest"
dest = 'C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\downloaded_file.xls'

download.file(url = target, destfile = dest, mode='wb')
```

Now, I save that as 'Sheet_Names.r' on my desktop and also save a batch file, with this inside: `'"C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe" CMD BATCH C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Sheet_Names.r'` without the quotes.  Then, I run the batch file, as administrator...but nothing happens...

All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I wrote something similar previously. See if that helps. https://shahronak47.wordpress.com/2016/11/30/scheduler-to-run-a-r-script-windows/

Comment: @RonakShah if you could post that here as an answer, I'd upvote it. Pointing to external sites isn't the StackOverflow pattern.

Comment: This other Q/A might help, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270935/r-executable-file-stops-after-writing-one-csv

Comment: Thanks guys.  I just updated my original post.  It seems like that should work, but it doesn't do anything.  Did dI miss something?  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, now it works.  You need to point to this: "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\R.exe"